# Space between columns in blockarray

Tags: tables, formatting, matrices, blkarray

I'm looking for a way to change the column space in a blockarray. I tried by setting `\arraycolsep` and `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}` but none of these solutions were successful. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\[
\arraycolsep=53.4pt
\small
\begin{blockarray}{*{3}{c}}
   & a & b \\
\begin{block}{c[*{2}{c}]}
   a    &   0   & 1 \\
   b    &   2   & 3 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result is :

[image: resulting matrix]

I'd like to add more space between the columns a and b of the matrix. Any idea how to achieve this? Ideally, the solution I'm looking for is still using blkarray but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea why, but it uses `\BA@colsep` so you need to access the command with `@` in its name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[\makeatletter\setlength\BA@colsep{53.4pt}\makeatother
  \begin{blockarray}{c c c}
        & a & b \\
    \begin{block}{c[c @{\hspace{50pt}} c]}
      a & 0 & 1 \\
      b & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...nope... that's not it.

Comment: @Werner aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrgggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @Werner sorry about that, fixed, as you may have guessed I borrowed your MWE as the OP did not supply one:-)

Comment: if you use `@{}` after the first labels column it will not insert the space there, just as in a normal tabular.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I edited my question so that the given example is a MWE

Comment: @Spazz that's Ok I ought really have been able to make an example of my own package without stealing Werner's and then forgetting to remove his changes:-)

Answer (score 6):

With `nicematrix` you get the desired spacing by setting `\arraycolsep`. And a friendlier syntax, by the way.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{20pt}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
 & a & b \\
a & 0 & 1 \\
b & 2 & 3
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{blockarray}{c c @{\hspace{50pt}} c}
        & a & b \\
    \begin{block}{c[c @{\hspace{50pt}} c]}
      a & 0 & 1 \\
      b & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this solution while still declaring columns with the syntax `*{3}{c}` ? I tried `*{3}{c}@{\hspace{50pt}}` but the result is quite strange. Also tried `*{3}{>{\hspace{50pt}}c}` but then columns labels aren't aligned with columns content.

Comment: @Spazz: Yes. You can use `c *{2}{c@{\hspace{50pt}}}` for the outer `blockarray` and `c [*{2}{c@{\hspace{50pt}}}]` for the inner `block`. However, for 2 columns its a bit superfluous to use the `*` notation. For larger blocks it might be useful. It would seem a bit weird to have the outer indices pushed out as well, but if need be, you can use `*{3}{c@{\hspace{50pt}}}` for the outer `blockarray`.

Answer (score 2):

The separating length is `\BA@colsep`, and by default,  it is equal to `tabcolsep`. I defined a new command to change it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setBAcolsep}[1]{\BA@colsep=#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \[ \small\setBAcolsep{53.4pt}
        \begin{blockarray}{*{3}{c}}
           & a & b \\
        \begin{block}{c[*{2}{c}]}
           a & 0 & 1 \\
           b & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]